# What is the data source of a merge document

Tags: microsoft-word, metadata, merge

I have a MS Word merge document (not of my own making).  To get the data for the merge, the file accesses a query in an Access database.  How can I discover exactly what that query is?  I know I can run a macro that will point to the database in which the query resides, but how do I drill down to the actual query(ies)?

In other words, give a word merge file, how do I discover the complete data source without knowing what it was beforehand?

Comment: See Microsoft Sharepoint Server, or desctop - WDS 4.0

Comment: Do you mean "where the data source still exists", or "where the data source is no longer there" (i.e. where you can't open the document without removing the data source)? Is it a .doc or a .docx?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the base merge document (ie the one with the merge fields and link to data source), if it is a docx file, rename it so it is a zip file (ie add .zip to end of filename).

Then have a look in the word folder of the zip file, and open the file called settings.xml.

Look for the tag with text like:  w:query w:val="SELECT